# Worksheet functions returning 0 when the actual value is ""

Tags: excel, lookup

For some time I've been aware that excel make a last minute decision to return 0 in lookup functions when the actual target value is "empty".  I know that the actual function returns the correct value because I got into the habit of using If(lookupfunction="","",lookupfunction), which is a pain but works.

I have a table with a vlookup in a calculated column which looks up another table based on a third table with a parallel structure (using tablename[@[name]] style referencing). Some of the entries in the source table are blank and the lookup was returning blank (to my surprise and delight).  I then deleted one of the non-blank entries in the source table and the vlookup returned 0 instead of "", just for the one I deleted.  If I delete another entry, it also reverts to zero instead of "".  I checked all of the formatting and it is all set to general so the zeros are not being hidden.

I guess that is by way of a bug report, but my question is: is there a neat way to pass "" through worksheet functions without them being converted to 0 all the time

Comment: Can you please post your formula? I'm only getting #N/A errors.

Comment: Update: I can control the value returned by putting a ' in the blank source cell.  If I do this the lookup returns a blank as desired.

Comment: sorry...

=VLOOKUP(StructureKPIsTable[@KPI],MetricsDefinitionTable,MATCH(R1C,MetricsDefinitionTable[#Headers],0),FALSE)

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. BTW, putting ' just forces the formatting to be Text, which is why it turns up blank.

Comment: Yep, but formatting as Text using the Number formatting does not work unfortunately.  It would be an elegant way to fix my problem if it did.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, it would have been an easier fix for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Excel formulas cannot return an Empty cell - empty gets coerced to zero.
 A cell containing ' or "" or space is not an empty cell but contains a zero-length string: functions like Lookups will happily return a zero-length string - it looks like an empty cell but is not.

Comment: I was thinking the same exact thing, but I couldn't find any documentation on it from MS.

Comment: OK, thanks Charles.  Its interesting that the coercion happens after the function returns its value.  So you can still capture it with an if statement.  It would be nice to have an ifEMPTY function to save having to enter the formula twice.